# The Inheritance of C++

Tags: c++

Recently, I am learning the Inheritance.
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


class Pad{

public:

    void Show(){
        cout<<"this is pad ";
    }  

};

class Decorator: public Pad{
protected:
    Pad* mpad;
public:
    Decorator(Pad* ipad){
        mpad = ipad;
    }   

    void Show(){
        mpad->Show();

    }
};


class CoverDecorator: public Decorator{

protected:

public:
    CoverDecorator(Pad* ipad):Decorator(ipad){

    }

    void Show(){
        mpad->Show();
        cout<<"with Cover";
    }

};


int main()
{

    Pad* ipad = new Pad;

    Pad* Coverpad = new CoverDecorator(ipad);   
    Coverpad->Show();


    return 0;
}
```

But I found that it printed out  "this is pad"  instead of  "this is pad with Cover" .
It means that in `Coverpad->Show()`, it implements the function `void Show()` of class Pad instead of implementing the `void Show()` of class CoverDecorator.

Why and How do I make it implement the `void Show()` of class CoverDecorator ?

Thanks!

Comment: declaring `show` `virtual` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make the base function `virtual`:

```
class Pad{

public:

    virtual void Show(){
        cout<<"this is pad ";
    }  

};
```

It is also important to note that when creating a virtual function, although the it is not needed, it is good practice to label the derived functions with the `override` keyword:

```
class Decorator: public Pad{
protected:
    Pad* mpad;
public:
    Decorator(Pad* ipad){
        mpad = ipad;
    }   

    void Show() override {
        mpad->Show();

    }
};
```

Declaring a function as `virtual` basically means that that function will not bind statically at compile time, and instead bind dynamically during the runtime of the program (this allows polymorphism).

Comment: Why  mark overriding functions as virtual when you have the `override` keyword?

Comment: @erlc You're right; back when I learned about polymorphism, I was not aware of the `override` keyword. I just did some reading on it and it would seem using it on the derived function is the better way to go; fixing it now / thanks for the tip!

Comment: Don't forget about the destructor for `Pad` -- it should either be virtual or protected, or else deleting through a base pointer will be UB.

Comment: @Ike Although that is out of the scope of the question, this is an important fix to avoid memory leaking. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

With C++ inheritance, declaring certain methods within the base and derived classes as `virtual` means they are subject to change within the derived classes and will be called as such.

`virtual <return type> <name>(){}`